# Requests SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] Windows

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, anaconda

When I set verify = False I get a 200 response.  When I set verify = True I get an SSL error. I updated certifi and opensll, but not sure what to do next.  I am using Anaconda on Windows. I believe I need to download the domain validation certificate as *.crt or *pem file from https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?client_id=MYCLIENTID, but not sure how to do that exactly.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 326, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 329, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Anaconda\envs\seatgeek\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.seatgeek.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERT
IFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)'),))

import requests

with open("id.txt","r") as file:
    read_data = file.readlines()
    client_id_data = read_data[1]

CLIENT_ID = client_id_data

payload = {'performers[home_team].slug': 'warriors','client_id': 
CLIENT_ID}

response = requests.get('https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events', verify = True, 
params=payload)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can export certificate for the link https://api.seatgeek.com/2/events?client_id=MYCLIENTID using chrome/firefox browser , here is a wikihow link https://www.wikihow.com/Export-Certificate-Public-Key-from-Chrome